# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, c#-3.0

I am trying to make a method in my interface, which gets checkout history, but when I try to implement method like this :

```
 public IEnumerable<CheckoutHistory> GetCheckoutHistory(int id)
    {
        yield return _context.CheckoutHistory
            .Include(h=> h.LibraryAsset)
            .Include(h=>h.LibraryCard)
            .Where(h => h.LibraryAsset.Id == id);
    }
```

I get error :'object' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Does anybody know what could be the sollution?

namespace LibraryServices
{
    public class CheckoutHistory : ICheckout
    {
        private readonly LibraryContext _context;

```
    public CheckoutHistory(LibraryContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public void Add(Checkout newCheckout)
    {
        _context.Add(newCheckout);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Checkout> GetAll()
    {
       return _context.Checkouts;
    }

    public Checkout GetById(int checkoutId)
    {
        return GetAll().FirstOrDefault(checkout => checkout.Id == checkoutId);
    }

    public IEnumerable<CheckoutHistory> GetCheckoutHistory(int id)
    {
        yield return _context.CheckoutHistory
            .Include(h=> h.LibraryAsset)
            .Include(h=>h.LibraryCard)
            .Where(h => h.LibraryAsset.Id == id);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have imported `System.Data.Entity` in your class. You are trying to use an extension method from this namespace.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```